# Setting the input method

Tags: android, android-input-method

I'm looking at the setInputMethod function of the InputMethodManager class, and I see it receives 2 arguments: A token and the ID of the input method. I can get the ID from the InputMethodInfo class, but I have no idea where to get the token from. It's not the window token which I can get from the view, but another kind of token, so how can I obtain it? Thanks.

Comment: I want to call this function: 
public void setInputMethod (IBinder token, String id)
but I don't know from where I can get the value for the first argument.

Comment: are you using Aidl communication? Basically Ibinder used to communicate with remote service,, if u don't need pass a null value..